# How to search multiple columns using INDEX and MATCH?

Tags: excel-formula

I have an Excel formula that matches a cell on one spredsheet and searches through a column on another, then returns the contents of adjacent cells to that column for any matches. The problem is I need to search through two different columns for that match, and if either of the columns contains the match, return another adjacent cell. I have tried using:

```
=INDEX('PNO Lookup'!$A:$A,MATCH(Summary!D25,'PNO Lookup'!$G:$J,0))
```

which should search from column G to column J, but I get a #VALUE error. Can anyone explain how I would search both column G and J for the value in cell D25?

Comment: Try this `=INDEX('PNO Lookup'!$A:$J,MATCH(Summary!D25,'PNO Lookup'!$G:$J,0))`

Comment: That one returns a #N/A error unfortunately.

Comment: `$G:$J` is **not** *'two different columns'*.

Comment: @david_10001 you have not given the column index number. The formula works like this `Index(lookup range, row number, column number) ` you are missing the column number

Comment: @PraveenRKaruppannan `column number` is optional.  If the range is only one column or row it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=INDEX('PNO Lookup'!$A:$A,MIN(IFERROR(MATCH(Summary!D25,'PNO Lookup'!$G:$G,0),1E+99),IFERROR(MATCH(Summary!D25,'PNO Lookup'!$J:$J,0),1E+99)))
```

Comment: Good for column G **or** column J; personally I found the match column description confusing. e.g. *'two different columns'* vs, *''PNO Lookup'!$G:$J'* vs. *'from column G to column J'* vs. *'both column G and J'*.

Comment: yes I assumed the first and the last.  Either way yours is shorter.

Comment: don't know about that, been on the road a lot lately.  I don't see that stopping anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Along the same idea as the previous answer but a little shorter.

```
=INDEX('PNO Lookup'!$A:$A, IFERROR(MATCH(Summary!D25, 'PNO Lookup'!$G:$G, 0),
                           IFERROR(MATCH(Summary!D25, 'PNO Lookup'!$H:$H, 0),
                           IFERROR(MATCH(Summary!D25, 'PNO Lookup'!$I$I, 0),
                           MATCH(Summary!D25, 'PNO Lookup'!$J:$J, 0)))))
```